# How to setup timeout for ejb lookup in websphere 7.0

Tags: java, websphere, ejb-3.0, jndi, websphere-7

I have developed a standalone Javase client which performs an EJB Lookup to a remote server and executes its method.The Server application is in EJB 3.0

Under some strange magical but rare situations my program hangs indefinetly, on looking inside  the issue it seems that while looking up the ejb on the server, I never get the response from the server and it also never times out.

I would like to know if there is a property or any other way through which we can setup the lookup time in client or at the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very nice article that discusses ORB configuration best practices at [DeveloperWorks here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1109_col_vanrun/1109_col_vanrun.html). I'm quoting the three different settings that can be configured at client (you, while doing a lookup and executing a method at a remote server);

> - **Connect timeout**: Before the client ORB can even send a request to a server, it needs to establish an IIOP connection (or re-use an
>   existing one). Under normal circumstances, the IIOP and underlying TCP
>   connect operations should complete very fast. However, contention on
>   the network or another unforeseen factor could slow this down. The
>   default connect timeout is indefinite, but the ORB custom property
>   `com.ibm.CORBA.ConnectTimeout` (in seconds) can be used to change the
>   timeout.
> - **Locate request timeout**: Once a connection has been established and a client sends an RMI request to the server, then LocateRequestTimeout
>   can be used to limit the time for the CORBA LocateRequest (a CORBA
>   “ping”) for the object. As a result, the LocateRequestTimeout should
>   be less than or equal to the RequestTimeout because it is a much
>   shorter operation in terms of data sent back and forth. Like the
>   RequestTimeout, the LocateRequestTimeout defaults to 180 seconds.
> - **Request timeout**: Once the client ORB has an established TCP connection to the server, it will send the request across. However, it
>   will not wait indefinitely for a response, by default it will wait for
>   180 seconds. This is the ORB request timeout interval. This can
>   typically be lowered, but it should be in line with the expected
>   application response times from the server.

Comment: Thanks for the article Kurtcebe, it really answers the thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code, which performs task & then waits at most the time specified.

```
Future<Object> future = executorService.submit(new Callable<Object>() {
public Object call() { 
return lookup(JNDI_URL); 
             }
         });

     try {
            Object result = future.get(20L, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //- Waiting for at most 20 sec
     } catch (ExecutionException ex) { 
       logger.log(LogLevel.ERROR,ex.getMessage());  
       return; 
    }
```

Also, the task can be cancelled by `future.cancel(true)`.

Comment: Hmm that's a nice solution , even i thought a similar implementation using a seperate thread.

Comment: But I was looking for a parameter or property that i can setup so that the library itself handles the timeout. Is there something like that.

Comment: @AkhandpratapSingh If this can accomplish what you are trying, why to go for library. You can configure timeout duration in property file. Quartz might be helpful, but seems overkill to me.

Comment: Hmm... Shouldn't there be a WAS configuration parameter for it?

Comment: @ŁukaszSiwiński The client is Java SE & performing lookup there. I presume client isn't running on WAS.

Answer (score 0):

Remote JNDI uses the ORB, so the only option available is `com.ibm.CORBA.RequestTimeout`, but that will have an affect on all remote calls.  As described in the [7.0 InfoCenter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/uorb_rsetg.html), the default value is 180 (3 minutes).